# concatenating string in the property being observed in the observer

Tags: ember.js, ember-model, ember-components

I have a component in which I am observing a property from model and model is fed to controller in controller setup as controller property 'model'. Model has properties age, salary, rank. The property in component is to be entered by user.

The component will be called as:

```
{{ui-slider prop="age"}}
```

OR

```
{{ui-slider prop="salary"}}
```

This is not the complete component but it explains my problem.. The **Component** is :

```
App.UiSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

prop:function(){
    return this.get('prop');
}.property('prop'),

modelPropertyObserver:function(){
    console.log("property is "+this.get('targetObject.model').get(this.get('prop'));
}.observes('targetObject.model.'+this.get('prop')),

didInsertElement:function(){
   console.log("Element inserted");
}

})
```

This is not working. When  I observe property like  
`.observes('targetObject.model.age')` 
then it works fine. 
 But now it is showing 
`cori_component.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: this.get is not a function`

I also tried `.observes('targetObject.model.'+this.prop)`
 Though it doesn't show any error but the observer doesn't work.

How to concatenate the 'prop' property to the observer?
Or is there any way that I can concatenate the string inside component and then substitute it into observer.

Comment: Did you tried using ES6 template literals like this \`targetObject.model.${this.get('prop')}\`

Answer (score 1):

Innstead you can try,

```
{{ui-slider prop=model.age}}
```

and

```
modelPropertyObserver: Ember.observer('prop', function() {
    console.log("modelPropertyObserver");
})
```

I don't think the below one is acceptable.

```
.observes('targetObject.model.'+this.get('prop'))
```

Comment: this in that context is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Though this is not the exact answer I was looking for but I got the hint how to solve the issue. Now my component is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following by overriding init and setting the property there (I've done this to have a dynamic computed property). I'm using Babel to have ES2015 features (like `...arguments` and string interpolation 
)

```
init() {
this._super(...arguments);
this.set('value', Ember.computed(`model.${this.get('attribute')}`, function() {
  return this.get(`model.${this.get('attribute')}`);
}));
}
```

I assume by the documentation that you could replace `Ember.computed` with `Ember.observer` (and replace the corresponding method signature - snippet bellow [copied from the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html))

```
Ember.observer('value', function(sender, key, value, rev) {
// Executes whenever the "value" property changes
// See the addObserver method for more information about the callback arguments
}
```